# cannot get OutputStream content from sqlcmd process when running with java ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, sql-server

Need to run sqlcmd to control local-connections to the database.
When i try to read the OutputStream to get the sql "prompt", the read() method simply never returns.

tried running the process with ProcessBuilder and Runtime.getRuntime().exec()
also tried running under "cmd /c"
when running sqlcmd from the command line, i get a prompt like "1>". expected to see that in the OutputStream ...

this is my code - i simply call start with "sqlcmd"

code example:

```
package org.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println(start("sqlcmd"));
        System.out.println(send("select * from spt_monitor\ngo\n"));
    }

    public static Process process = null;

    public static String start(String command) throws Exception {
        if(process != null && process.isAlive()) {
            throw new Exception("another session already exists");
        } else {
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            process = builder.start();
            return "";//response();
        }
    }

    public static String send(String command) throws Exception {
        if(process == null || !process.isAlive()) {
            throw new Exception("no local session exists");
        } else {
            process.getOutputStream().write(command.getBytes());
            process.getOutputStream().flush();
            return response();
        }
    }

    private static String response() throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        char[] array = new char[1024];

        System.out.println("reading output...");
        try (InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())) {
            int len;
            do {
                len = isr.read(array);
                if(len > 0)
                    sb.append(String.valueOf(array));
            } while (len > 0);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes and although I already mentioned this it confirms that you are attempting to read to EOF (though that should be `>= 0` for EOF) and therefore you will never see the prompt because the stream will block

Comment: now i see what you meant by trying to read to EOF. the problem is that the first time i call read (on line "len = isr.read(array);") it never returns. so there never is ANY data on the stream...

Comment: Can you please be explicit about what the "it" is in *it never returns*

Comment: oh of course, sorry for the lack of clarity. the first call to read never returns, as if no data is ever written to the stream...

Comment: *the first call to read never returns* How do you know?

Comment: @user3673620 The sub-process `sqlcmd` has written out the prompt and is waiting for a command. You haven't shown any code which sends any commands or terminates the `sqlcmd` STDIN, therefore you won't get any back from `isr.read(array)`. 
So the situation you have is as expected: `isr.read(array)` blocks because it has read up to the "prompt" and is waiting for the end of STDOUT stream of the sub-process, or for more data to be written to STDOUT.

Comment: g00se - in debug mode i reach the read(array) line and when i try to execute it, it blocks and never returns.

Comment: DuncG - this code is connected to a REST API which calls start("sqlcmd") i expected to be able to read the prompt. also in another attempt, i ignored the output and sent a query, but again, the first call to read(array) blocks and never returns

Comment: *in debug mode i reach the read(array) line and when i try to execute it, it blocks* OK. I can only say either it hasn't received the command and therefore hasn't responded or you might be reading the wrong stream as I mentioned earlier. Please give us a printable example of a command that fails

Comment: @user3673620 The prompt has been read, but `read(array)` is trying to read the following character and therefore is blocking because without a SQL command there is nothing more from the stream until EOF

Comment: i've updated the code to a printable example. the result is a printout of "reading output..." without ever ending. note that you may try to read also the start("sqlcmd") response by changing the return from method "start" as commented. same result ...

Comment: @DuncG I am obviously assuming that *the first invocation* of read is what's meant. Please tell me I'm right ... ;)

Comment: So when you go to cmd.exe normally and enter `sqlcmd` and hit enter, it returns with a prompt?

Comment: @g00se It doesn't make much difference first or not: `response()` calls `read(array)` in a loop which calls `ch = read()` in a loop so the code will always block at some point ... unless `process.getOutputStream().close()` gets called (or command to exit is sent) and then `response()` will eventually return a value.

Comment: start is meant to open the sqlcmd session and send is meant to sent consecutive queries. but i can't get a response from start, and if i don't try to get a response from start, then i dont get a response from send, so i either case the program hangs with no output. and yes, when you run sqlcmd in cmd.exe you get "1>" prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This hopefully will give a clearer explanation as to why your code does not finish as you expect. You have started sub-process `sqlcmd`, and `sqlcmd` outputs a prompt, receives your command(s), processes each command and outputs another prompt.

The `sqlcmd` process is waiting for more commands but you have not sent more after `send()`. At this point though your `response()` call is stuck in a blocking loop trying to read the character AFTER the last prompt. This means that `response()` will never exit normally - even though it has processed some of the commands and appended to a `StringBuilder`.

To see this more clearly, fix a small bug in `response()` with incorrect size of the array in `String.valueOf()` and add a `System.out` to tell you what has been read so far by `response()`:

```
private static String response() throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char[] array = new char[1024];

    System.out.println("reading output...");
    try (InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())) {
        int len;
        do {
            len = isr.read(array);
            if(len > 0) {
                String r = String.valueOf(array, 0, len);
                System.out.println("response() has read a value: "+r);
                sb.append(r);
            }
        } while (len > 0);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Re-run and you should see that `isr.read(array)` HAS worked and should print out the results of `select * from spt_monitor` but will block on next or following `isr.read(array)` call when the prompt has been printed - and `response()` never exits because no more commands are received to process.

There is no more STDOUT to process unless you send `sqlcmd` an exit command OR terminate the STDIN which causes the `sqlcmd` process to end - both of which would mean that `response()` could exit normally.

You should be able to make `response()` work by terminating the STDIN by adding `process.getOutputStream().close()` at the end of `send()` or after calling `send()`. However that means that `sqlcmd` will exit.